# Powershell ISE NOT found in Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

i am not able to see the powershell ise application in my windows serevr 2012 OS,Search window .
Below is the screenshot of my issue:

Whats wrong with my OS? Does anything is corrupted?

```
[ps-ise][1]


 [powershellisenotfound][1]
```

Comment: Powershell ISE isn't necessary installed on the server. https://www.google.by/search?client=opera&q=how+to+install+powershell+ise+windows+2008+r2&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=how+to+install+powershell+ise+windows+2012+r2

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable powershell via following steps. Open PowerShell Window, and type the following commands:

```
Import-Module ServerManager 

Add-WindowsFeature PowerShell-ISE
```

For more details see this [msdn link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/guruketepalli/2012/11/06/enable-powershell-ise-from-windows-server-2008-r2/).

As far as I know PowerShell ISE is not enabled for WIN server operating systems. Reason: WIN 2012 is designed for headless usage in clouds. Therefore it won't make sense to enable GUI based PowerShell ISE.

Comment: this is wrong, 2012 contains ISE in the box, if you install gui version (the reason its not there for core version, is because its impossible to use ISE on core)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late for the original poster, but it's available to be added as a Feature in the Server Manager. Go to Programs and Features --> Turn Windows features on or off --> Expand Features (in the left pane) --> Add Features (upper right) --> Check the appropriate box in the Add Features Wizard and install.
Note: It's called Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE) so it's down in the "W" section and not "P".